# Implementing DNS message NAME compression algorithm in Python

Tags: python, regex, search, dns

In DNS messages, domain names are represented like so:

```
Address    Value
----------------------------------------------------------------
0x00C      0x5 s t o r e 0x7 e x a m p l e 0x3 c o m 0x0
0x023      0x4 b l o g  0xC012
```

At address `0x00C` we have `store.example.com` and at address `0x023` we have `blog.example.com`. `0xC012` represents a pointer to `0x012` where `example.com` begins in the first domain name, so we don't have to repeat it.

I managed to turn a domain name into an array of labels using the following code:

```
labels = []
for part in self.domain.split('.'):
    label = part.encode('ascii')
    length = len(label).to_bytes(1, 'big')
    labels.append(length + label)
```

This gives me the following array:

```
[b'\x04blog', b'\x07example', b'\x03com']
```

But I have trouble building a regular expression or an efficient function that would search the part of the message that's already written for either `\x04blog\x07example\x03com\x00` or `\x07example\x03com\x00` or `\x03com00`. I'd like to find the longest match I can. I tried building a regex like this:

```
(((\x04blog)?\x07example)?\x03com)?\x00
```

But it seems the regex engine prefers just matching for `\x00` in that case. How do I fix that?

There's also another issue: we could technically add `my.blog.example.com` which would need to contain `0x2 m y 0xC023` with `0xC023` pointing to `blog.example.com`.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, yes, I'm programming this purely as a learning experience.

Comment: Hint: you will have less problems if you parse things right to left and store, in a dict for example, the full name as key and encoded value as value. Start with `com` you encode it as `0x3 c o m 0x0` and you keep `cache['com'] = position`,  then you go to `example`, encode it and put `example.com` in `cache` with appropriate position, etc. Then for compression, before any encoding you test if the value exists in `cache` already. This is one way to do it without regex. You could have a look also on how it is done in current DNS libraries to give you ideas...

Comment: I realized I wrote pointers over one byte instead of two. I tried fixing them, hopefully I didn't get any of the hex math wrong. I also wrote addresses over three hex digits, considering a message can take up to 512 bytes (0x200).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sorry for the false hint I gave you, there are far simpler things to do. In fact there are far simpler things to do than using a regex here. regex are far too powerful to do this, you can achieve the same result without.

DNS message format is defined in [RFC 1035 : "DOMAIN NAMES - IMPLEMENTATION AND SPECIFICATION"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035)

Name compression is explained in section 4.1.4.
Note also that you have to take into account the case insensitive aspect, as outlined in section 2.3.3

It should be the case in the following code that can surely
be optimized, with example names taken from RFC:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

names=['F.ISI.ARPA', 'FOO.F.ISI.ARPA', 'ARPA']
cache={}
pos=0
results=[]

for name in names:
    labels = name.split('.')
    while len(labels):
        key = '.'.join(labels)
        if key.lower() in cache:
            results.append((cache[key.lower()] + 2**15 + 2**14).to_bytes(2, 'big'))
            pos += 2
            break
        else:
            label = labels.pop(0).encode('ascii')
            length = len(label).to_bytes(1, 'big')
            results.append(length + label)
            cache[key.lower()] = pos
            pos += len(label) + 1
    else:
        results.append(b'0')
        pos += 1



print(results)
```

which produces:

```
[b'\x01F', b'\x03ISI', b'\x04ARPA', b'0', b'\x03FOO', b'\xc0\x00', b'\xc0\x06']
```

If instead using your example:

```
names=['store.example.com', 'blog.example.com', 'my.blog.example.com']
```

it produces:

```
[b'\x05store', b'\x07example', b'\x03com', b'0', b'\x04blog', b'\xc0\x06', b'\x02my', b'\xc0\x13']
```

Comment: Yeah, I came to the conclusion I might need a cache not too long after asking the question. Oh, I see, you write the name from left to right, adding its entries to the cache progressively, and as soon as you're left with a remainder that's in the cache, you put a pointer. Off course!

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, pointers in a NAME are made of two 1 bits followed by an offset from the very top of the message (over the rest of two bytes). Domains can be written in various sections of a message, and there's always some more data between domain names. So it won't be as easy as starting `pos` at 0 and incrementing it like that, but this code gets the general idea across.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil  yes the position will have "gaps" depending on where you are but this really depends on the message you are building; you will just need to  have like a generic function where you pass a name and current position and it will encode the name, based on the current content of the cache, at the given position and increment it.

Comment: Actually, I went with `(0xC000 + len(message)).to_bytes(2, 'big')` to create and store the pointer in the cache before doing `message.append(length + label)`.